# How to restrict routing from change in angular 5 application on condition base?

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-routing

I am working on angular 5 application and facing a situation that I am on a component and I don't want to allow the user to switch the routing until he/she will not answer the question showing on that component. After answering the question user can switch the routing and enjoy the system.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't get Observable.of(true) to work in an AuthGuard in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42317622/cant-get-observable-oftrue-to-work-in-an-authguard-in-angular2)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieved desired behavior  using auth guard in Angular 2+.

[Here](https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-route-guards-bf7a4ca13ae3) is a nice article which explains how you can block certain routes based on different conditions.

**Update:**

you can create your router configuration like below.

```
import { AuthGuardService as AuthGuard } from './auth/auth-guard.service';

export const ROUTES: Routes = [
  { 
    path: 'profile',
    component: ProfileComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard] 
  }
];
```

Then your AuthGuardService should look like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, CanActivate } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate {
  constructor(public auth: AuthService, public router: Router) {}
  canActivate(): boolean {
    if (!this.auth.isAuthenticated()) {
      this.router.navigate(['login']);
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

The point to note here is, you can inject any service to your AuthguardService (Injecting service in to another service) and construct your logic.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 1):

Guards are cool and stuff, but if you only need to disable a link until the user answers a question, you can provide an empty route with a ternary operator to disable the link.

Given that you store the answer in the `answer` variable :

```
<a [routerLink]="answer ? ['your', 'path'] : null">Continue</a>
```

Giving null routes cancel the routing of the application, and guards are useful when you want to prevent routing on certain modules, but for only one link ... It's overkill.